# How do substution-permutation networks work?

Tags: block-cipher, algorithm-design, substitution-cipher

I understand what is going on in higher level. But I don't understand what's really going on in page 3 and 4 of [this](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~ozan.karsavuran/CS470/slides/CS470.02.BlockCiphers.pdf) slide.

Specifically,

1. How $S_0$ and $S_1$ is used? What goes in what goes out?
2. How exactly do key bits determine which s-box is to be used at each position? Position refers to what?
3. Is the function $f$ on page 4 exactly the same SP network on page 3?
4. Why split plain text into left $L$ and right $R$?
5. Why XOR $L$ with $R$ after applying $f$?
6. Why rotate after applying last $f$?
7. Why is XOR used? Why not some other bitwise operation?

[Here are the preceding slides](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~ozan.karsavuran/CS470/slides/CS470.01.Intro.pdf) for reference.

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35243292/3899583

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of a question in stackoverflow, answered there as in the comment above by @vojta